# How to put Date/Time value into a field?

Tags: apex, datetime

How can I pass a `Date/Time` value into an object's field? For example, if the `AllocatedTime__c` on the `Case_User__c` object were of this type, what would I use?

```
Case_User__c cuser1 = new Case_User__c(
    Available__c='00546000000hZUx', 
    AllocatedTime__c=''
);
```

Comment: Where is your soql query?

Comment: This question does not seem to have anything to do with SOQL...that seems to just be a flub by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass a date time value to populate data in your field.

You can use [newInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) method from DateTime to construct your datetime value. There are couple of more method which can be used, please check DateTime methods.

```
Datetime myDate = Datetime.newInstance(2008, 12, 1, 12, 30, 2);
Case_User__c cuser1 = new     
    Case_User__c(
    Available__c='00546000000hZUx', 
    AllocatedTime__c=myDate
);
```

Comment: Or even simpler, `Datetime.now()`! Probably more instructive to show `newInstance` though.